# Remotely change config for app.config

Tags: c#

Is it possible to change the configuration remotely through network? I have searched on internet, web.config is able to do so, through Aspnet_regiis. But for normal app.config, is there a way? I have considered to use windows service, but is there other approach that can make it happen?

Let's say I have keys in my exe.config:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="Height" value="120"/>
<add key="EnableSSL" value="false"/>
<add key="EnableCiphered" value="false"/>
<add key="EnableMask" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

I want to change it from another computer to another computer remotely. I want an advice if there is better approach to do it, except using Windows Service.

Comment: Can you explain the context here?

Comment: Use a remote desktop connection maybe? Or some other means to access the computer remotely. If there was a standard way to modify the config of every application, that would be a terrible security hole.

Comment: What if there are too many server to change? That's why I want to create a WinForm Proj to handle the situation..

Comment: You could use automation tools like remote PowerShell.